# commuting with compacts

Tags: operator-algebras, compact-operators

Let $S$ be a shift on $\ell_2$. Is there any non-zero compact operator $K$, commuting with $S$? If yes, how to find a bounded operator $T\in\mathcal{B}(\ell_2)$ which does not commute with any non-zero compact $K\in\mathcal{B}(\ell_2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean with $l_2$ the hilbert space $l_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and the shift defined by $Se_i = e_{i+1}$. Then if we assume it is true, we get

$$ \| Ke_{i} \| = \| SKe_{i} \| = \|KSe_{i}\| = \| Ke_{i+1} \| $$

By induction we then have $\|Ke_{i}\| = \|Ke_{j}\|$ for all $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $K$ can only be compact if $K = 0$.

So the only compact operator commuting with $S$ is the zero operator.

Comment: The same proof works for unlateral shift on $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ (either left or right, take adjoint to change left/right).

Comment: I am not convinced yet. The commutator of $S$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ contain an isomorphic copy of $L^\infty(\mathbb T)$. That space has nonzero compact operators (finite range functions).

Comment: To me the answer seems OK. Indeed, $(e_j)_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is weakly null in $\ell_2(\mathbb{Z})$ so $(Ke_j)_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is norm null.